# C Sockets - Linux posix send function will keep Old Data after closesocket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, client

i don't know whether my question is valid or not, but i have problem with my client side linux socket and i cannt find any similar issues on stackoverflow,
the problem is i try to send data to server on TCP, and we have failure situation by cable disconnect,
send returns successful, and then recv fails, i close the socket, and try another connection with new data,
in a close time range between two retries, on server side we have both datas, the first failed one over the cable, and the second one which was normally done,

i've tried so many options to flush the first buffered data,
like NO_LATENCY, SO_LINGER, shutdown socket, and ...
but none of them works, 
the old failed data is sending with new data, together,
am i missing something here ? or it is some sort of linux kernel config ?

Comment: EIther (1) the server will receive any data sent over the old socket before it receives the close of that socket; or else (2) it will receive a 'connection reset' and probably none of the data. You might consider whether your timeout period is too short. It should be long enough to cope with a brief cable pull, like the rest of TCP does.

Comment: thanks for the tip, (2) solved my problem, but still i don't get the whole idea, "It should be long enough to cope with a brief cable pull", can you please explain more

Comment: I don't know what more you're looking for. How long is your read timeout?

Comment: logical explanation of tcp, first it was 10 and send and recv, and now its 60, 60 solved the problem

Comment: You're not going to get a 'logical explanation of TCP' in a StackOverflow comment. Your read timeout should be two or three times the expected average response time.